# amp img is not working on dropdown menu

Tags: amp-html

I just can't figure out why amp-img won't work (it's not creating img tag inside and does not show image)

So I have dropdown menu, which I'm converting to amp friendly, no JS, pure CSS.

http://jsbin.com/wutujibiku/edit?html,output

If you hover first item, dropdown menu open with 2 items, first item should have image, but it's not showing.

Bug? or there's way around?

Help is much appreciated.

Looks like amp does not like hidden element and if that element is displayed later, amp-img is not calculating image

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check if your CSS implementation is supported in this [AMP CSS docs](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/responsive/style_pages). It seems that not all CSS style is supported and looking at some [AMP-img](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-img/) samples, your implementation is not included.